# Heading / Title

Tags: html, css

I have attached an example of what I am trying to achieve using html/css (if you cannot see the image it is: first name and surname, then second line is job description). I would like the all the text (both lines) to be forced justified (left and right) within a div but I am not sure if it is possible. I have tried a few things with no success. I would rather not use an image, so any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post on jsfiddle.net and give us the URL

Comment: For starters, AFAIK H7 and H8 don't even exist. 

Appart from that, are you going to apply those styles to several things in your site or is going to be only for that (or a few more others)?

Comment: ok big mistake with h tags. would I use a div instead ? as its one off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align-last: justify`:

```css
.justified {
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}
.justified:after {
    content: ".";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/En4wt/

[source](http://kristinlbradley.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/cross-browser-css-justify-last-line-paragraph-text/)

Comment: Tried this within the div but no success

Comment: Also the words "web guru" is not justified, it looks left aligned on your example ?

Comment: @GavinWynne - Whoops, I missed one part.  Updated.

Comment: wow this looks good. Not sure how this would work with my current html/css ?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers generally do a crap job at full justification. If you are a design company using this to promote yourself, I'd avoid it.

Also, it only works on paragraphs of text, not single lines.

You can try tweaking the CSS letter spacing to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: ok cool, I was thinking of changing the spacing manually but was not sure how each browser might handle it ? and just thought i could force the justification instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to style the title, you can create specific styles for it. Try combining font-size with letter-spacing until you get the effect you want to achieve.

Text align: justified is for a different purpose, it's meant for paragraphs (or long blocks of text). If you don't have enough text to reach the end of the line, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, decided to change the design